# Wrong location using [NSEvent mouseLocation]

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsevent

I make a iphone remote mouse controller application for Mac: the iPhone application sends the coordinate values to the Mac, which then processes mouse location value.

To get the current mouse location on the Mac, the receiver calls [NSEvent mouseLocation].

The value for x is always correct, but the value for y is wrong.

I used a "while" loop to process this event.

```
while (1) {
    mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

    while ((msgLength = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) != 0) {
          CGPoint temp;
          temp.x = mouseLoc.x;
          temp.y = mouseLoc.y; // wrong value
          ........
```

A y value is different at each loop period. For example, y value is 400 at first loop, y is 500 at next loop; then y is 400 again at next loop.

The mouse pointer is coming up and down continuously, and sum of two different y values is always 900. (I think because the screen resolution is 1440 * 900.)

I don't know why it happens, what to do, and how to debug it.

Comment: As far as I know, `mouseLocation` is not a static method.

Comment: @David [mouseLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-BBCIGACJ) is a class method of `NSEvent`.

Comment: Oh, I thought it wasn't. Sorry!

Comment: @이민규 did you ever figure this out? I am having this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way you can get the proper Y value:

```
while (1) {
mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
NSRect screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
NSInteger height = screenRect.size.height;

while ((msgLength = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) != 0) {
      CGPoint temp;
      temp.x = mouseLoc.x;
      temp.y = height - mouseLoc.y; // wrong value
      ........
```

Basically, I've grabbed the screen height:

```
NSRect screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
NSInteger height = screenRect.size.height;
```

Then I take the screen height and subtract the Y coordinate of mouseLocation from it because mouseLocation returns coordinates from the bottom/left this will give you the Y coordinate from the top.

```
temp.y = height - mouseLoc.y; // right value
```

This is working in my app that controlling the mouse position.

Comment: @Nicholaz it should work no problem if both monitors are the same resolution - otherwise you might need some extra math/checking which monitor the mouse is on - you'd have to try it to find out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it would be changing without seeing more of your code, but there is a good possibility it has something to do with the fact that `mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];` returns a point whose origin is at the bottom left of the screen, instead of the top left where it would normally be.

Answer (score 2):

Get right position code:

```
CGPoint mousePoint = CGPointMake([NSEvent mouseLocation].x, [NSScreen mainScreen].frame.size.height - [NSEvent mouseLocation].y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

```
let mousePosition = CGPoint(x: NSEvent.mouseLocation.x, y: (NSScreen.main?.frame.size.height)! - NSEvent.mouseLocation.y)
```